# Mobile application payment gateway for Ukraine

Tags: flutter, dart, payment, gateway

I'm developing the application on Flutter(dart) where users should be able to receive payments for some services. For example, user A offers service and user B should be able to pay for this service by a payment card. All users are from Ukraine.

I thought to use stripe gateway and there is [Flutter library for this](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment). But my understanding is that stripe does not work with Ukraine. Users are able to pay but they are not allowed to receive payments. Am I right?

What should I do? Should I look for another payment gateway that works with Ukraine?

Comment: I can't vote to close while the bounty is open, but I think this question is off-topic, because it's asking for a recommendation of a third-party service, rather than about a programming problem.

Comment: you can give this package a go if you want: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paystack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Option 1:***

Use PayPal
[PayPal flutter integration](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-flutter-379fbb3b87f5)

***Option 2:***

Look for a bank (Ukrainian Bank) that provides SDK for flutter or API to do the payment.
If SDK is not available but API is you can modify the guide provided above to achieve the payment infrastructure.

**Option 3:***

Accept payment from Stripe and use your local bank to transfer money from your account to the recipient.

In that way, all the payment will go to your/your company's bank account(Ukraine bank account) from Stripe. For payouts, you can use the banks API to send the payment to the recipient directly from your bank account without the help of stripe to send the money to the recipient.

or Receive the payout  request and process the payment manually (not recommended)

Comment: Customers in Ukraine are not able to receive funds to their PayPal accounts.